# Django Forms Showing No Input Fields

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-templates

instead of the whole form i am just seeing the submit button not the form fields

**Goal**: get form fields to load and be able to submit form.

**views.py** file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.views import generic
from friendsbook.models import Status,User
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .forms import CreatePost

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name='uposts/home.html'
    context_object_name='status_object'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Status.objects.all()

class  post_detail(generic.DetailView):
    model=Status
    context_object_name='user_profile'
    template_name='uposts/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        abc=Status.objects.all()
        return abc;

def create_post(request):
    form=CreatePost()
    return render(request,"uposts/createpost.html",{'form':form})
```

**forms.py** file

```
from django import forms
from friendsbook.models import Status

class CreatePost(forms.Form):

    class meta:
        model=Status
        fields = ("title","username" )
```

**createpost.html** file inside designated folder

```
{% extends "friendsbook/structure.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">{%csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

i also try by python shell but it's of no use.
look at this it's giving me empty string instead of form fields.

[image]

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of errors here.

First, to create fields from a model your form needs to inherit from `forms.ModelForm`, not `forms.Form`.

Secondly, the inner class needs to be called `Meta`, not `meta`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not using a `ModelForm`, you need to define the `field`s. And you can get rid of the `model = Status` declaration.

Try this:

```
from django import forms


class CreatePost(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    username = forms.CharField()

    class meta:
        fields = ("title","username" )
```

Since it's not a `ModelForm`, the `form` has no idea what fields there are in the `Status` model. And it has no way to instantiate the fields (since they are not defined).

I think you probably want to use a `ModelForm` though, unless there's some compelling reason not to.